# Using Node (API) to display data in Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, asana

I am still new to the concept of MEAN Stack and right now i am trying to display a list that I get from the Asana API in a simple website that I made. My issue is that in order to get the list that I need from Asana I use nested functions and I have no clue how to send the result to my frontend.

```
var callback = function() {console.log("test")};    

client.projects.findAll(callback).then(function(projects) {

projects.data.forEach(function(project){
   var id = project.id;
    var name = project.name;       
    console.log(name);  
  });   
});
```

If I run the program I do get the list that I want inside my console and would like to know how to display the list from index.html file.  Basically how to send the name variable to the frontend.

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert your values in your $scope, for example:

```
client.projects.findAll(callback).then(function(projects) {
  $scope.projects = projects;     
});
```

and then in your HTML use an ng-repeat to display the values, for example:

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projects | track by $index> 
   <span>{{project.value}}</span>
</div>
```

This way, you'll create a div for every project element inside your array, displaying his property .value (but you can substitute .value with any of your properties)  with the brackets notation {{ }}